# How to earn tez?

Tags: rewards, tezos-reward-distributor

I'm new to community (not a developer). I want to get some tez, so I would be looking for pointers to earn/mint tez and how to start with it?

Answer (score 0):

Tezos is an active, independent, blockchain. It is not a token of another chain. To acquire tez on the mainnet you need to use any number of available exchanges (coinbase, binance, kraken, etc) to trade into XTZ.

Once you have XTZ you can use any wallet to delegate to a baker and earn a % reward each cycle.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to buying tez on exchanges, you can also buy tez with credit card [on tzkt](https://tzkt.io/buy-tezos).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to buying tez you can also earn it.

[tezos.com](https://tezos.com/careers/) lists a number of Tezos related jobs, not all of which for developers, and many of them of a remote nature. These employers will likely be willing to pay part of their wages in tez.